# JSwing - Re utilse event handler with different parameter value

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to code a telephone and the first thing I wanted to do is to assign a different sound to each button pressed.

I don't want to write ten handlers such as this one:

```
private void buttonOneHandler(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    try{

        buttonSound = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("resources/buttonOne.wav"));
        buttonSound.open(ais);
        buttonSound.loop(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Instead, I would like to use a unique handler, which accepts a String parameter (the route to the wav file), so that each button changes `getAudioInputStream` parameter value.

Is that possible?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static class PlaySoundActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private String soundPath;

    private PlaySoundActionListener(String soundPath) {
        this.soundPath = soundPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // play the sound at this.soundPath
    }
}

...

button1.addActionListener(new PlaySoundActionListener("resources/buttonOne.wav"));
button2.addActionListener(new PlaySoundActionListener("resources/buttonTwo.wav"));
button3.addActionListener(new PlaySoundActionListener("resources/buttonThree.wav"));
```

Note that a MouseListener is not the appropriate listener to use with a button. ActionListener is the one which is invoked when a button is clicked, and regardless of the way it's clicked (with the mouse, the keyboard, a keyboard shortcut).

Comment: There it goes, JB Nizet! Now it's working. I have two questions regarding your code, though (and pardon me if their answers are obvious): 1) Why does it have a private constructor? 2) Where do you recommend to put the lower code (addActionListener)? Inside a custom initialization method?

Also, thanks for the useful appreciation about avoiding to use the MouseListener. It's so right.

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: It has a private constructor because it's in a private class. So even if the constructor was public, it would only be accessible from the enclosing class anyway. But it doesn't matter much. Adding the action listener should indeed be part of the initialization of your panel/dialog/frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by writing a single ActionListener, and registering it with each button. 
You'd then have to use JButton(Action) constructor to force the button to generate your custom action on click.

This is covered in the swing tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html

Comment: Oh, thanks, YurDeD. That was useful and correct indeed. I should have gone to that tutorial before. Thanks again!